# Batch read from firebase based on an array of document IDs - Swift 4

Tags: firebase

I have an array with specific document IDs (that are all in the same collection) and would like to query them one time and getting a qsnapshot with all of those documents, instead of having to request them individually one at a time with a for loop. Is there a way t do this?